# is it possible to call sql server stored procedures from Azure Embedded power bi to generate reports?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-web-app-service, business-intelligence, powerbi-embedded

Is it possible to call sql server stored procedures from Azure Embedded power bi to generate reports? Then we will integrate it with azure webapplication.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But Stored Procedures are only supported in Import models, or in Paginated  Reports.  Table-valued functions can be used in DirectQuery models.